# Google Script: print school schedule data for each teacher

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

This is my first question here. I have searched the site to the best of my knowledge, but haven't found any other examples of my question.

Here is the Google Sheets file
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HxyhoxuPK8H8_vhLg0ZZ-THyOn1cn9nPYRyls8y47iM/edit?usp=sharing

I have 2 sheets in the same Google Sheets document.
The first, "schema" contains a base-school schedule for a teacher, with different classes in different blocks. This needs to be replicated, so that all teachers has this exact setup - so that all unique users have the same 50 lines of schedule data - only with their allocated classes.

The second sheet contains information about the users. Each line contains a UNI-login username and their designated class 1a-1, 4a-1 and 8a-1 for user uni12345 for example. 1a-1 needs to replace 1, in "uni12345"'s schedule data.

I would like all these data (a lot of lines) combined into one sheet, fx. called "combined" - but you get your pick on the name :-)

I have made a Combined Example sheet, that presents how I would like the output for user1+2 in the list.

If the question already is partly answered elsewhere, I'll be happy to look at that also!

Edit:
Since my original question I have made it work - only now I'm hitting the 6min script exectution time limit. Any way around that, eg. optimization?

```
    function merge() {

  var CurrentDate       = new Date() ;  
  var CurrentDateString1 = Utilities.formatDate(CurrentDate, "GMT", "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss") ;

  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 // var mergeSht=ss.getSheetByName(CurrentDateString1);                     
  var users=ss.getSheetByName('users');
  var schema=ss.getSheetByName('schema');

  var mergeSht = ss.insertSheet();
  mergeSht.setName(CurrentDateString1);

  var usersValues = users.getDataRange().getValues();
  var schemaValues = schema.getDataRange().getValues();

  var counter = 1;


  for(var n=1; n < usersValues.length ; n++){

    var usersValue = usersValues[n];

    var uniName = usersValue[5];
    var levelInd = usersValue[2];
    var levelMellem = usersValue[3];
    var levelUdsk = usersValue[4];

// Logger.log(usersValues[n][5])

    for(var i=1; i < schemaValues.length ; i++){ 

      var schemaValue = schemaValues[i];

      if (schemaValue != null && schemaValue.length > 0) {

      var level = schemaValue[3];
      var subject = schemaValue[4];
      var room = schemaValue[5];
      var day = schemaValue[6];
      var position = schemaValue[7];

        var levelAfd = getlevel(level,levelInd, levelMellem, levelUdsk);
        Logger.log(levelAfd);

        // print

      var row=[];
        row.push(counter++,'','unilogin:'+ uniName, levelAfd, subject, room, day, position);
      mergeSht.appendRow(row);


      }
    }
  }
   }

    function getlevel(level, levelInd, levelMellem, levelUdsk){
        switch (level)
    {
        case 1:
            return levelInd;
        case 4:
        return levelMellem;
        case 7:
           return levelUdsk;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added my new solution to the question; only now I'm hitting the 6min max exection time on Google Scripts.

Comment: What does the execution transcript look like?

Comment: Like this: https://pastebin.com/jrgSFQVp

Comment: You might get a small performance improvement by incorporating the switch from getLevel into the main loop. However, the rest of the code looks  okay to me.  You may have to figure out a way to break the function up into pieces that you run consecutively.  Perhaps there something in the usersValues that could allow you to do them in smaller sections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something else you could try:
This code creates a new array which avoids having to push each row one by one.  Instead, at the end in loads the entire mergeSht all at one time.

```
function merge() 
{
  var CurrentDate       = new Date() ;  
  var CurrentDateString1 = Utilities.formatDate(CurrentDate, "GMT", "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss") ;
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 // var mergeSht=ss.getSheetByName(CurrentDateString1);                     
  var users=ss.getSheetByName('users');
  var schema=ss.getSheetByName('schema');
  var mergeSht = ss.insertSheet();
  mergeSht.setName(CurrentDateString1);
  var usersValues = users.getDataRange().getValues();
  var schemaValues = schema.getDataRange().getValues();
  var counter = 1;
  var mergeA=[];//Small change
  mergeA.push(['H1','H2','H3','H4','H5','H6','H7','H8']); //First row is headers
  for(var n=1; n < usersValues.length ; n++)
  {
    var usersValue = usersValues[n];
    var uniName = usersValue[5];
    var levelInd = usersValue[2];
    var levelMellem = usersValue[3];
    var levelUdsk = usersValue[4];
// Logger.log(usersValues[n][5])
    for(var i=1; i < schemaValues.length ; i++)
    { 
      var schemaValue = schemaValues[i];
      if (schemaValue != null && schemaValue.length > 0) 
      {
      var level = schemaValue[3];
      var subject = schemaValue[4];
      var room = schemaValue[5];
      var day = schemaValue[6];
      var position = schemaValue[7];
      var levelAfd='';

        switch(level)
        {
          case 1:
            levelAfd=levelInd;
            break;
          case 4:
            levelAfd=levelMellem;
            break;
          case 7:
            levelAfd=levelUdsk;
            break;
          default:
            levelAfd='';
            break;
        }
        if(levelAfd)
        {
          mergeA.push([counter++,'','unilogin:'+ uniName, levelAfd, subject, room, day, position]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  mergeSht.getRange(1,1,mergeA.length,mergeA[0].length).setValues(mergeA);
}
```

Comment: That sounds interesting! However I get the error "Google Sheets Script Error - Cannot convert Array to Object[][]"

Comment: the error happens on line 58, "mergeSht.getRange(1,1,mergeA.length,mergeA[0].length).setValues(mergeA);"

Comment: I made a small change in the mergeA array.  Try it again.

Comment: Works perfectly! 15000 rows created in 10 seconds! Awsome